# How to add switch in tableview cells

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My application navigation based and  view is UITableviewController. I need to add switch control for ON and OFF for particular UIViewtable cell. How to add.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UISwitch in a UITableView cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770019/uiswitch-in-a-uitableview-cell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also a classic, this question has been asked a lot here already. For example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770019/uiswitch-in-a-uitableview-cell). Search for `UITableView` and `UISwitch` to get way more results.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a switch in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method found in the [`UITableViewDataSource` Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    UISwitch *aSwitch = [[[UISwitch alloc] init] autorelease];
    [aSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:aSwitch];
    return cell;
}
```