# iOS Settings screen ideas

Tags: ios

I'm in the process of building a universal app and now working on the Settings screen. The settings screen is simple with a slider control and two switch controls. I'm not using Settings bundle and using simple NSUserDefaults class. I was checking the pttrns.com site and really like the Settings screen from the screenshot shown below. I would like to develop a similar one and would like to know how it is done and get some ideas from people here. I'm new to iOS and really appreciate any help.

Also, any pointers to good backgrounds(similar to the one shown below) I can download for free?[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Idea #1: don't use the Xcode tag for unrelated questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it they're using a grouped `UITableView`, with a section per 'setting' control, and the description of each control as a section footer.

So, set up a grouped tableview with a funky background, like the ones *Erway Software* suggested, and then if you need help adding UISwitches to your tableview, just look at this question: [UISwitch in a UITableView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770019/uiswitch-in-a-uitableview-cell) - add a method that updates NSUserDefaults every time the corresponding Switch value is changed.

Comment: Thank you and wanted to ask whether it is a good idea to add the app title at the bottom of the Setting screen. Because, by looking at the Setting screenshot above, the user wouldn't know the name of the app if he has left the app idle on the screen for a while.

Comment: It is completely up to you how you brand your app, and in this case it does depend on how familiar the user is with your app at the point of choosing settings. For instance, if they are forced to alter settings at the start of the app, then it would be a good idea to remind the user of your app's branding. This could still apply for a normal settings screen, however you should focus on not 'over-branding', but instead on passive UI elements that represent your brand, such as the color scheme, fonts and graphic schemes. If you add a title, present it as a logo in a separate section at the end.

Answer (score 3):

A great site for backgrounds and patterns is [Subtle Patterns](http://www.subtlepatterns.com). I have used this on several projects and love it!