# UISwitch in a UITableView cell in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I followed [UISwitch in a UITableView cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770019/uiswitch-in-a-uitableview-cell) to put a UISwitch inside a tableview. Here is the code:

```
UISwitch *mySwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
cell.accessoryView = mySwitch;
```

But the problem is that when I put the table into editing mode:

```
self.tableView.editing = YES;
```

The UISwitch dissapears.

Do you know how can I go around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `UISwitch` to **`contentView`** of cell.

The `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell` object is the default `superview` for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the `contentView` so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

```
[[cell contentView] addSubview:switch];
```

Comment: Ok, this answered my question, so I'll give it to you when I can (I have to wait 7 more minutes). I didn't know about the contentView. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @abhishekkharwar can you have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438459/how-to-properly-position-a-uitableview-cell-subview-to-the-right which follows your advice but I ran into another problem? Thanks!

Comment: did you try to add autoresizingmask on uiswitch ?? try to add UIAutoresizingMaskLeft and then let me know

Comment: That's exactly what they told me on that question. you know your stuff! ;) Thanks again!