# How to properly position a UITableView cell subview to the right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I'm trying to add a UISwitch to my table cells on the right.
I first tried [adding it to the accesoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770019/uiswitch-in-a-uitableview-cell), but when I entered to editing mode in the table, the UISwitch dissapeared. 
So now I [added it to the contentView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438077/uiswitch-in-a-uitableview-cell-in-editing-mode), which is working great, no dissapearing. But it adds it to the top left corner.

So I'm trying to add it to the right but I want to stay away of absolute values in order to support all sizes and orientations.

So I'm trying with this code:

```
[[cell contentView] addSubview:switchView];
switchView.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width - 
                                    switchView.frame.size.width, 
                              0,
                              switchView.frame.size.width, 
                              switchView.frame.size.height);
```

But this is what I'm getting:

[image]

Any ideas how can I fix this?

Comment: I think you should try create Custom Cell, and use autoresize properties for the controls you add in the cell, so that on rotation the controls adjust by themselves.

Comment: Mmm... I could. But I'm trying to do it all in code IF possible. If I don't get any good answers, I'll definitely go that route. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate autoresizing masks or layout constraints on the switch.

If you're using springs and struts, you want the switch to have a flexible left margin only. This will keep it a fixed distance from the right hand edge of your superview - the content view is very likely resized between you adding the switch and it appearing on the screen.

To set this mask:

```
switchView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

If you're using Auto layout (which makes not using specific frame values very easy!), you need to pin the switch to the right edge of the superview - `[switch]-|` in visual format.

Comment: I'm actually using neither! As I'm doing it all by code. If I don't get any code-only solutions and I end up going this route, I'll award the answer to you. Thanks!

Comment: This is a code-only solution. You can set autoresizing masks or layout constraints in code. All views have a default autoresizing mask, which usually favours pinning to the top and left. I'll edit the answer.